# PM2 Refuses to ask for SSH key password no matter what?

Tags: pm2

Config;

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'My App',
      script: './dist/app.js',

      // Options reference: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],

  deploy: {
    production: {
      key: '~/.ssh/id_rsa',
      user: '....',
      host: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx',
      ref: 'origin/master',
      repo: 'git@bitbucket.org:..../....',
      path: '/srv/my-app',
      ssh_options: ['StrictHostKeyChecking=no', 'PasswordAuthentication=yes'],
      'post-deploy':
        'yarn && yarn build && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js --env production --update-env',
    },
  },
};
```

Currently `'PasswordAuthentication=yes'` will return `git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).`

If I set it to no, it will return `Permission denied (publickey,password).`

At no point does it ever prompt me for the SSH key password, it just straight up denies it. It only ever asks for the system password.

How can I solve this since their documentation is pretty garbage and the only thing they suggest on there is making an SSH config which I have done and still doesn't work.